# Choosing CRS to georeference map from 1857 (North America)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, archaeology

I am trying to georeference a map in QGIS from Beale's Expedition of 1957-1858, using coordinates he recorded for camps in his daily log.

Here is the map: https://digitalcollections.nypl.org/items/760ae1c0-2a3a-0136-9b52-6538b070a3d3
Here is his journal with the coordinates: https://archive.org/details/GR_216

I don't know what CRS to use in QGIS to get the points close to reality. I am very new to this.

Comment: I suggest you use the grid on the map, indicating degrees west and north, aka WGS84/EPSG4326.

Comment: @Erik why would you suggest WGS84?  I'd think NAD27 would be closer.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the grid, I didn't think of that, it helped a lot. I also was puzzled over what datum to use, if anyone has clarification on which datum to use and why that would be really helpful!

Comment: It's interesting--Before Clarke's 1858 ellipsoid, Airy 1830, Everest 1830, and Bessel 1841 are all about 800-1000 meters smaller. Beale is giving lat/lon coordinates to the nearest second (roughly 30 meters). You might try just using a modern datum because there are no transformation to convert from the older ellipsoids/datum anyway.